# Array splice method with non number argument

Tags: javascript

I came across a code like:

```
let array = ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
array.splice('val0');
console.log(array); // array =[], every element was removed from the array
```

which is obviously wrong as per the definition of Array.prototype.splice in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), but I'm kind of curious after trying different argument types and then showing different results (like `array.splice(true)`). But I couldn't guess what is doing under the hood, specially when the parameter is a string as is not returning some kind of error due to a NaN conversion.

Comment: Any false-y value is treated as 0, and `NaN` (`'val0'` coerced to a number) is false-y.

Comment: true is converted to 1, hence why the method returns the first array element.

Comment: According to the specification, the first argument is converted using ToInteger. Seems like it will return +0 for your string. But I’m not sure why it would remove all elements. See: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.splice

Comment: @schteppe `splice(0)` removes all the elements

Comment: @MattEllen that makes sense after reading the rest of the spec! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the actual<sup>1</sup> specification:

- [Array.prototype.splice](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.splice)

  > Let relativeStart be ? ToInteger(start).
- [ToInteger](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tointeger)

  > - Let number be ? ToNumber(argument).
  > - If number is NaN, +0, or -0, return +0.
- [ToNumber](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-tonumber)

  > If the grammar cannot interpret the String [...], then the result of ToNumber is NaN.

`ToNumber('val0')` returns `NaN`, hence `ToInteger('val0')` returns `0`. With `array.splice('val0');` you are effectively executing `array.splice(0);` which removes all the elements from the array.
And with `array.splice(true)` you are effectively executing `array.splice(1)` which removes all elements after the first one.

---

[1] While MDN is a great resource, it is *not* the specification of ECMAScript/JavaScript. When you are interested in the underlying details, always check the actual specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html

Comment: To add for the lazy, `array.splice(0)` removes all elements because if the 2nd parameter `deleteCount` is omitted, it will be equal to array.length - start -> in this case 0. Same thing with NaN as this answer explains.